# Python: TLS 1.2 (Cipher) handshake worked after Postman Installation

Tags: python, windows, ssl, tls1.2

On Windows Server 2012 R2, Python 3.10.5, below code

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("utslogin.nlm.nih.gov")
headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
conn.request("POST", utslogin_path, "apikey=" + self.api_key, headers)
                res = conn.getresponse()
```

throws below exception

> Unexpected err=SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] cer tificate verify failed: unable to get
> local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'), type(err)=<class
> 'ssl.SSLCertVerificationError'>

When looked at WireShark log, found ciphers TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 are missing.

Installed Postman to understand whats wrong, and after that Python code started working.

I am not sure what Postman did here, is it installing missing ciphers if yes then where are those added on Windows OS? Followed Microsoft link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel and further group policy settings but these ciphers not found.
Anyone know where these ciphers will be added by Postman on windows?

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with ciphers being used. The library is telling you it got a certificate from the server that it can't validate because it doesn't have the corresponding CA root certificate (and any needed intermediate). So you either have to load that specific certificate on your side and mark it as secure (and redo that each time it expires), or properly add the relevant CA in your trust store.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, how to get certificate in trust store and after Postman installation how that is happening?

Comment: https://ssl-tools.net/subjects/8bc19e845b981d61cf5469211a68b8e311336d90 after adding self-signed pem  under CA Root, the handshake is successful 

@PatrickMevzek appreciate your hint helped, it took time to find the right certificate but at the end issue resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that postman is installing certificate "Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority" under trusted root CA. Downloaded and installed from https://ssl-tools.net/subjects/8bc19e845b981d61cf5469211a68b8e311336d90, code ran successfully without any exception

Thank you for the hint @PatrickMevzek

Comment: Security recommendation though: fetch CA certificate from the CA website itself, instead of other sites. Or at least compare what you got with that "pristine" version. Most of the times, no problems, but to be 100% secure each part needs to be checked by itself (CA should publish fingerprints of their certificates, so you can check that also without even having to download again certificate to compare), and specially CA certificates as those are "fully trusted" so anything coming as signed by them is trusted fully.

Comment: Yes I did compare, thumbprint and issuer before installing vert